# Use string variable containing expression in selectExpr of dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm having problems trying to use a variable containing my expression in the `selectExpr` of a dataframe.

So I have my variable as:

```
expression = '"substr(value,1,1) as qffffffffbf3ef0cf","substr(value,2,1) as q6a0aaf20"'
```

And trying to use this on the dataframe as:

```
ascii_df.selectExpr(expression).show(1)
```

However I keep getting a mismatched input error. If I put the expression in directly as follows it works:

```
ascii_df.selectExpr("substr(value,1,1) as qffffffffbf3ef0cf","substr(value,2,1) as q6a0aaf20").show(1)
```

Is there a way of doing this in PySpark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in fact using two separate expressions. When using them directly in `selectExpr` you are using the expressions as two separate arguments to `selectExpr`:

```
selectExpr("substr(value,1,1) as qffffffffbf3ef0cf","substr(value,2,1) as q6a0aaf20")
```

However `expression` is a single string which is why it will not work. Instead change it to:

```
expressions = ["substr(value,1,1) as qffffffffbf3ef0cf","substr(value,2,1) as q6a0aaf20"]
ascii_df.selectExpr(expressions).show(1)
```